# How can I print a value with its class that are inside a list?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, data-science, p-value

I have to print the pvalues that are less than alpha. For that I am getting the values like this:

```
X = dataset[['rank', 'ethnicity','gender','language','age','cls_perc_eval','cls_did_eval','cls_students','cls_level','cls_profs',]]
Y = dataset['score']
X = add_constant(X)
fit = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
pVals = fit.pvalues
print(pVals)
```

If I print pVals it looks like this:

```
const            1.900673e-26
rank             1.265173e-01
ethnicity        2.816922e-03
gender           2.898288e-05
language         6.945070e-02
age              1.329203e-02
cls_perc_eval    6.599640e-02
cls_did_eval     5.058437e-01
cls_students     5.686794e-01
cls_level        8.568453e-01
cls_profs        8.568453e-01
dtype: float64
```

Then I have the following code where I am checking which pvalues are lower than alpha (alpha = 0.05):

```
alpha = 0.05
for i in pVals:
    if i < alpha:
       print(i)
```

But if I print i it is just printing just the number and not the class, the output looks like:

```
1.900672940949515e-26
0.0028169220335196596
2.898287594231024e-05
```

Is there a way I can print the class and the number, so it would look like this?:

```
Const - 1.900672940949515e-26
Rank - 1.265173e-01
```

Answer (score 0):

`pVals` is a pandas series. To iterate over the index and the value you should use the `items` method. Docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html#pandas.DataFrame.items.

```
for k, v in pVals.items():
    if v < alpha:
        print(k, v)
```